# ORACLE: Getting Data Extract (>50 Million records) in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having a set of records say A
A : `SELECT SINGLE_COLUMN FROM SAMPLE_TABLE1 WHERE SOME_FILTER`.
It returns a set of numbers
[image: Result set for A]

Now I need to execute a query which will get the input from A and get the extract (say B) for that output.
B : `SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM SAMPLE_TABLE2 WHERE COL1 IN (A)`.
Taking input from A the above query will return a result set
[image: Result Set B -- Desired Output]

This extract is expected to have more than 50 Million records.

I've tried to write a cursor to fetch this but couldn't find the right way.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_insert
   IS
      SELECT single_column
        FROM sample_table1
       WHERE some_filter;

   TYPE ty IS TABLE OF output_data_table%ROWTYPE;

   ty_cursor   ty;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_insert;

   FOR i IN ty_cursor.FIRST .. ty_cursor.LAST
   LOOP
      SELECT col1, col2, col3
        FROM sample_table2
       WHERE col1 IN (i);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Need help to find a way to get this big extract. Currently I am having only SQL Developer in my workplace and Input tables are all my DB's internal tables

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: What will you do with 50+ million rows, once you extract them? If you'd want to import them elsewhere, consider using data pump with the **QUERY** parameter which enables you to apply a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Why do you insist on SQL Developer? There might be better tools to do that. Moreover you did not mention desired output format.

Comment: Edited my question to Clarify!!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way will be to use one single select:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 
  FROM SAMPLE_TABLE2 
 WHERE COL1 IN ((SELECT SINGLE_COLUMN FROM SAMPLE_TABLE1 WHERE SOME_FILTER))
```

or

```
SELECT s2.COL1,s2.COL2,s2.COL3 
  FROM SAMPLE_TABLE1 s1
  JOIN SAMPLE_TABLE2 s2
    ON s2.COL1 = s1.SINGLE_COLUMN
 WHERE s1.SOME_FILTER
```